# Is it possible to create a copy button in Azure DevOps Wiki pages?

Tags: azure-devops, copy

I am looking to get a copy button function embedded in an Azure wiki page, any ideas?

I understand the text editor in Azure does suppport HTML, unfortunately javascript is also needed for me to be able to do this with my own knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there isn't such a default feature. As you mentioned, the text editor in Azure wiki supports HTML, but javascript is needed when trying to add a Copy button. I noticed that there's already a feature request [Azure DevOps (VSTS) Wiki Copy Code Button](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-vsts-wiki-copy-code-button/421282). You can follow it and add some comments. Hope we can have this feature in the future.